# Shell Script to extract the value from XML file

Tags: xml, shell

Can any please help me to write the shell script to find the value from the below xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log>
<logentry revision="36">
    <author>XYZ</author>
    <date>2014-07-15T14:47:18.328479Z</date>
    <paths>
        <path action="A" localPath="ABC" kind="unknown">/branches/ABC</path>
        <path action="A" localPath="ABC" kind="unknown">/branches/ABC</path>
        <path action="M" localPath="DEF" kind="unknown">/branches/CDF</path>
        <path action="M" localPath="DEF" kind="unknown">FRG</path>
    </paths>
    <msg>added</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

I want to extract the value of the localPath i.e "ABC" and "DEF" as output and write in one file.

Comment: BTW, do you **really** have two adds, and then two different modifications, of the exact same file? I wonder if the perceived need for a `sort -u` step is an artifact of your anonymization, rather than something that could ever happen with the genuine data.

Answer (score 2):

Use an XML-aware tool. For example:

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/log/logentry/paths/path/@localPath' file.xml
```

Output:

```
 localPath="ABC" localPath="ABC" localPath="DEF" localPath="DEF"
```

which you can further process

```
$ xmllint --xpath '/log/logentry/paths/path/@localPath' file.xml \
  | sed 's/"/\n/g;' \
  | grep -v '^ ' \
  | sort -u
```

to get

```
ABC
DEF
```

or using [xsh](http://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh)

```
open file.xml ;
$h := hash @localPath /log/logentry/paths/path ;
for { keys %$h } { echo (.) ; }
```

Output:

```
ABC
DEF
```

Comment: Is the output format for `xmllint --xpath` documented with strong enough guarantees to make the following string manipulation forwards-compatible?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I don't know, that's why I included the output here, too.

Comment: @choroba:Thanks for your reply. I tried to run the command xmllint --xpath '/log/logentry/paths/path/@localPath' file.xml ,but it seems --xpath is not available. It is giving me error unknown option --xpath. Can you please tell me to fix this or do I need to use any other option.?

Comment: @user6376225: You can try upgrading xmllint.

Answer (score 1):

...or, with [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v /log/logentry/paths/path/@localPath -n
```

...emitting:

```
ABC
ABC
DEF
DEF
```